# How to see the "index" information of .a (archive) file?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, indexing, archive

I suppose gcc linker by default calls ranlib to inject index information to archive files(.a).

But

1. how can I see this "index" by any linux command?
2. Is it used/useful by linker when linking to generate executables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [GNU ranlib man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ranlib):

> ranlib generates an index to the contents of an archive and stores it
>   in the archive.  The index lists each symbol defined by a member of an
>   archive that is a relocatable object file.
>
> You may use **nm -s** or **nm --print-armap** to list this index.
>
> An archive with such an index speeds up linking to the library and
>   allows routines in the library to call each other without regard to
>   their placement in the archive.